# Echo the same thing on one page over and over again

Tags: php, oop, class, echo

I'm having some trouble with a project. To understand the problem it's useful to give a little backgroundinfo.

So, I'm creating a sleepingdiary. What I want to create is the following. When you click on day 1, the comment you added appears in the box on the left. The commentbox on the right is for the doctor who comments on your sleeping behaviour.

So far, so good. I get both comments from the database. But when I click on day 2, I should see the comments from day 2. However this doesn't work. Currently I just managed the click on day 2 with jQuery, maybe that's the problem. But how to fix it otherwise? Create a page for every day?

Please don't let the amount of code scare you away. :)

[image]

Saving on the right day works fine, printing after saving a new comment works fine as well. But it's echoing the same loop that causes the trouble I guess.

Here's my code:

**echo the comment in phpinclude/feedbackday1.php**

```
<?php   
        if(mysqli_num_rows($feedbackPatient) > 0)
        {
            while($oUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($allUsers))
            {
                echo $oUser['DiaryOpmerkingen'];
            }
        }
?>
```

**how I get the days in feedback.php**

```
<div id="book1">
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <input class="confirmday" name="day" value="1"/>
            <?php include("phpinclude/feedbackday1.php"); ?>
        </form>
    </div>
    <!-- einde dag 1 -->
```

**The function in my User.class.php**

```
public function getFeedback($p_iUserid) {

    include("Connection.php"); //open db

    /*$dayid = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['day']);*/    
    $id = $_SESSION['id'];

    /*DiaryId = {$dayid}*/
    try
    {
        $sql = "select DiaryOpmerkingen, DiaryDoctorcomment from tblDiary 
                WHERE fk_UserId = ".$p_iUserid."
                AND DiaryDay = '".$this->Day."';";
        $rResult = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
        return $rResult;
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        // no connection database
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

**On the top of the feedback.php - page**

```
include("classes/User.class.php");

$oUser = new User();    

if(!empty($_POST['patientfb']))
{
    try
    {
        $oUser->Patientfb = $_POST['patientfb'];
        $oUser->Day = $_POST['day'];

        $oUser->saveFeedbackP($_SESSION['id']);

        $feedback = "Uw commentaar werd succesvol toegevoegd.";
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        $feedback = $e->getMessage();
    }
}

$allUsers = $oUser->getFeedback($_SESSION['id']);
```

Totally stuck here. I really hope someone can help me out. Hope the question is clear. If you need more code, just ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello SQL Injection: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Comment: Uh, risky code there Kim. This is a perfect patient for MVC, you should try one of the following, http://codeigniter.com/ or http://www.yiiframework.com/. They'll take care of the security issues (to a good degree) and streamline the development process.

Comment: Yeah I know, but you have to know this is a project for school. We are still in the learning stage. So eventually everything will get safe. And yeah, I was planning to fix the SQL injection thing as last one, because I know for sure than that I won't forget anything. Of course I know SQL injection and I know it's dangerous, so, this isn't the final code. But yeah.. my question isn't answered yet. :s

Comment: If you know about SQL injection, it's a good habit to make sure all data is escaped before it gets to the database (or use PDO), always, whether it's for school, your little two-page hobby project, or a very large project. Then it becomes second nature and you don't forget about it. If you need to add the code as the final step, you're much more likely to forget it.

Comment: Arjan - FWIW, depending on the class/professor/teacher, one sometimes has to "dumb down" their work in order to stay on pace with the class and potentially keep from getting points taken away for doing things not in the assignment. Yes, it fosters bad habits; yes, it's dumb. Tell that to the school.

Comment: Did you solve this yet? If not, I'd be curious to know what your JS looks like, ie. what happens when you click on 'DAG 2' etc.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if i understand what your goal exactly is.

Maybe you could try to use an array? Sort it in such a way, that the last two comments always are in the beginning or the end of the array. And depending on the day the user clicks on, you could display only the two latest or first comments.